# What will be the passive form of 'He walks slowly on the road'?

Tags: verbs, active-voice, passive-voice

I'm preparing for my exam and need to know how to convert sentences from active to passive. My first response to this question was ***Slowly, he walks on the road***. But I thought that that's still active and also sounds a bit like Yoda. While giving the answer please give another example of conversion of an active simple present tense sentence to passive.

Comment: I'd recommend not using that book, if it really asks you to transform *He walks slowly on the road* into its passive voice. Consider, *He walks* or *I'm hungry*. Now, try to write them in the passive voice. It's nonsense, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

An intransitive verb like *walk* cannot sustain ordinary passivization because it has no Object which can be cast as the Subject of a passive clause.

**However**: if the active utterance contains a preposition phrase as predicative complement, the object of the preposition can in some circumstances be cast as Subject.

> Somebody slept *in **this bed***. → ***This bed*** has been slept in.

But this works semantically only if the action of the verb has some evident effect on the object of the preposition. The example above, for instance, makes sense because a viewer might deduce the sleeping from some disarrangement of the bedclothes.

But what about this?

> The road is being slowly walked on.

It's difficult to conceive circumstances in which that would be a sensible utterance—perhaps a Dungeons and Dragons game in which the dungeonmaster describes visible effects (such as footprints) of an invisible character walking on the road?

Comment: Also *Slowly, the road is walked (on) by him.*

Comment: A related passive construction that sounds like something a human might say: "I caution you, son, that this road has been walked - slowly! - many times before."

Comment: @Paul Nice. But, alas, it is the passivization of a different sentence, not OP's.

Answer (score 0):

As exposed by StoneyB, passive structures are impossible with intransitive verbs. Most of these verbs include the *stative verbs*. Examples of these are *fit, have, lack, resemble, suit.*
Michael Swan — *Practical English Usage* (thanks to Damkerng T.) explains that some transitive verbs, too, are seldom used in the passive. Most of these are 'stative verbs' (verbs which refer to states, not actions).
Here are some examples:

> » *They **have** a nice house*. (NOT <s>*A nice house **is had** by them*.</s>)
>       » *My shoes don't **fit** me*. (NOT <s>*I'**m not fitted** by my shoes*.</s>)
>       » *Sylvia **resembles** a Greek goddess*. (NOT <s>*A Greek goddess **is resembled** by Sylvia*.</s>)
>       » *Your mother **lacks** tact*. (NOT <s>*Tact **is lacked** by your mother*.</s>)
>       » *She was **having** a bath*. (NOT <s>*A bath **was being had** by her*.</s>)

Comment: I think you misunderstood entry 412.4 in the book (PEU) a little. The book says, "Some transitive verbs, too, are seldom used in the passive. Most of these are 'stative verbs' (verbs which refer to states, not actions)."

Comment: Oh yes, I read it a bit fast. I'll edit.